# Signing jars with multiple certificates for java webstart

Tags: java, java-web-start, certificate

I am trying to sign an application with multiple certificates, to allow different clients (that only trust one of them) to execute them with Java Webstart.

The signing seems to work fine, I see the multiple *.DSA/*.RSA and *.SF files in the META-INF of the jars.
However it seems that javaws only recognizes one of them and refuses to start if it doesn't trust exactly that certificate.

Does Java Webstart handle multiple signatures or does it not? Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not specified, so I suspect the web start client is just looking for a match for the first certificate it finds.

I found [this related bug report](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6848277) which unfortunately for you is marked WONTFIX. Your workaround is to have two separate deployments with the two separate signatures. Or work with your clients to find out why they trust one of your certificates but not the other ...

Comment: Yes, it seems you are right. I have to separate the deployments.